# Date format from url (JSON)

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

How would I be able to take the date format from a URL and turn It into 2 separate date values in `SwiftUI`. The format from JSON is `2019-11-06 18:30:00` and I'm trying to get it to show as Dec 5 and would also like it to separate the time and show 8:00PM, is this possible?

This is the code that references the start time:

```swift
let startTime: String

var startTime: String {
    return self.post.startTime
}
```

Comment: Parse the `String` to  `Date` object, then use two `DateFormatter`s to format it the way you want

Answer (score 0):

you can pass your string date to date with this function

```
func stringToDate(date: String, format: String) -> Date
{
    let date2 = date.count == 0 ? getCurrentDate(format: "dd-MM-yyyy") : date
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(identifier: "América/Mexico_City")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
    let dateDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date2)
    return dateDate!
}

func getCurrentDate(format: String) -> String
{
    let formD = DateFormatter()
    formD.dateFormat = format
    let str = formD.string(from:Date())
    return str
}

let dateA = stringToDate(date: "2019-11-06 18:30:00", format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")


if dateA < Date() //Date() always will be the current date, including the time
{
    print("dateA is older")
}
else
{
   print("dateA in newer")
}
```

play with the format [examples formats](https://nsdateformatter.com)

Comment: Hi, I've tired this but get an error saying - Use of unresolved identifier 'getCurrentDate'

Comment: Hi Andres, thanks for that, I've managed to get it to compile now but when I run It, it crashes. I get this error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @ItsOliMate try again please

Comment: Sorry still getting the same error on the line return dateDate!

Comment: how do you use the function? remember, change the format for your date string, your date string is like this format ´2019-11-06 18:30:00´? I updated my answer with other date

Comment: I'm trying to output it as text like this:  Text("\(stringToDate(date: venues.startTime, format: "MMM dd"))") Does that look OK? and yeah the format from the url is 2019-11-06 18:30:00

Answer (score 0):

Let's step around the fact that `2019-11-06 18:30:00` can't be represented as `Dec 5` and `8:00PM` and focus on the work flow you'd need.

The basic idea is to:

1. Convert the `String` to a `Date`, via a `DateFormatter`
2. Use a custom `DateFormatter` to format the `Date` to the required "date" value
3. Use a custom `DateFormatter` to format the `Date` to the required "time" value

This might look something like...

```
let startTime = "2019-11-06 18:30:00"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

if let date = formatter.date(from: startTime) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d"

    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.dateFormat = "h:ma"
    let timeString = timeFormatter.string(from: date)

} else {
    print("Bad date/format")
}
```

In my testing, this outputs `Nov 6` and `6:30PM`

Comment: Apologies I'm still new to this, I'm trying to put this into a list so that it gathers the date and time from the url and then I want it to show the date and time separate in a list view. Do you know how I could implement this code so I can get the values. I've tried adding it in myself but It just shows errors

Comment: Simplest solution would be to get the date/time values into a `Date` from the JSON as soon as possible, this forms part of your model.  You would then pass this onto your view which would then make decisions about how to display it

Comment: The only issue is I do not know where to put the above code, I have 2 classes that reference the startTime string, both of the lines are 

let startTime: String

and

var startTime: String {
    return self.post.startTime
}

where would I ideally need to put this so I can covert it correctly. 

sorry if this isn't clear I'm new to swift and this whole JSON thing is hard to understand

Comment: I would use Swift's in built support for JSON decoding. Have a look at [Swift Codable With Custom Dates](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-codable-with-custom-dates/) and [Decoding Formatted JSON Dates in Swift](https://dev.to/jrtibbetts/decoding-formatted-json-dates-in-swift-2odb) as start points